# Tail bounds for random Gaussian chaos?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, quadratic-forms, measure-concentration

Let $g = (g_1, \dots, g_d)$ be a sequence of independent standard Normal random variables, and suppose $\Sigma$ is a $d \times d$ (deterministic), real, symmetric, positive definite matrix. The Hanson-Wright inequality ensures that for $t > 0$,the upper and lower tails have the bound
$$
\max\bigg(\mathbb{P}\Big\{g^T \Sigma^{-1} g - \mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}) \geq t\Big\}, 
\mathbb{P}\Big\{g^T \Sigma^{-1} g - \mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1}) \leq - t\Big\}\bigg)
\leq 
\exp\Big(-c \min\big\{\frac{t^2}{\|\Sigma^{-1}\|_F^2}, \frac{t}{\|\Sigma^{-1}\|_{\rm op}} \big\}\Big).
$$
Above, $c > 0$ is a universal constant.

**My question:** do similar guarantees hold when $\Sigma$ is a random matrix? I am particularly interested in the case when we have
$$
\Sigma = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \otimes x_j.
$$
*(We assume that $x_j \in \mathbb{R}^d$  are iid, and have law such that when $n > d$, $\Sigma$ is nonsingular almost surely.)*

In this case, also assuming $x_j$ are mutually independent of $g$, I am wondering under what conditions we can expect to have exponential tail bounds for
$$
\mathbb{P}_{x, g}\Big\{g^T \Sigma^{-1} g - \mathbb{E}_x[\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1})] \geq t\Big\} \quad 
\mbox{or} \quad
\mathbb{P}_{x,g}\Big\{g^T \Sigma^{-1} g - \mathbb{E}_x[\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1})] \leq - t\Big\},
$$
where the probability is now over $g_1, \dots, g_d, x_1, \dots, x_n$. Any references or pointers to existing results are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the distribution of the $x_j$? If $P(x_j=0)>0$ then $E_x[trace\Sigma^{-1}]$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: But even somewhat mild conditions would prevent that from being true (e.g. $x_j$ has law absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure). This question makes sense, provided we assume that $\mathbb{E}_x[\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1})]$ exists and is finite?

Comment: Absolute continuity is not suficient. If $d=1$ and $n\in\{1,2\}$ then $E[(\chi^2_n)^{-1}]=+\infty$.

Comment: The last part of the abstract of https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10754 suggests the paper will have some answers to these issues, and possibly answers to your question.